# Change radiogroup if select combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox, radio-group

Hello i am have radiogroup with two items ('author' and 'price') and one combobox

```
{
                xtype: 'radiogroup',
                defaultType: 'radiofield',
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [
                    {
                        boxLabel: 'AUT',
                        name: 'author',
                        checked: true,
                        inputValue: '1',
                    }, {
                        boxLabel: 'PRI',
                        name: 'price',
                        inputValue: '2',
                        margin: '0 0 0 10'
                    }
                ]
            },
{
            xtype: 'combobox',
            width: 350,
            store: 'price.Book' 

        }
```

I am want if i am select in combobox, then checked true from  radiogroup item 'author' moved  to radiogroup item 'price'

What write in:

```
select: function(combo) { ???}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need something like this:

```
select: function(combo) {
    combo.up('form').down('radio[name="price"]').setValue(true);
}
```